# RelativeLayout does not adhere to set width when inflated

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, layout-inflater

I have a relativeLayout that I would like to use the theme.dialog android theme, it should have a set width of 240dip. When I specify the whole layout and it's children in xml, this works. However, when I try to inflate the xml to add more views (code below), the Layout fills the width of the screen.

```
Context context = this;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    RelativeLayout header = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.headphonepopupheader, null);
```

headphonepopup.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="240dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/closebutton"
    android:layout_width="24dp"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="216dp"
    android:background="@drawable/closebutton" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When inflating a `RelativeLayout`, do not use the `inflate()` method signature that you have there. Instead, use the `inflate()` that takes the parent container as the 2nd parameter and a boolean as the third. Supply the eventual parent for the `RelativeLayout` in the 2nd parameter, and if you do not want the `RelativeLayout` added immediately, pass `false` as the 3rd parameter.

Leastways, this recipe clears up all sorts of `RelativeLayout` inflation problems when using a `RelativeLayout` as the basis for a row in a `ListView`.

Comment: I'd like the relative to be the root of the ViewGroup. Is this possible?

Comment: @Frazerm63: Everything you create goes inside something else. Even if you call `setContentView()`, that `View` is put inside another container supplied by `Activity`. So, if you want this `RelativeLayout` to be your content view, call `setContentView()` and have Android inflate the layout for you.